# Empty Ads Issue w/ JS tags + DFP/Google Ad Manager

Tags: ads, google-dfp, google-ad-manager, mobile-ad-mediation

One of my clients is integrated with DFP/GAM SDK. They set up the JS tags that we gave them on DFP/GAM but are seeing “blank” ads appear in the ad slot whenever my company doesn’t respond to their ad request. I noticed that there is documentation for collapsing divs whenever an ad request is not filled on desktop, but don’t see any documentation for mobile apps (Android and iOS).

In creating my own test JS tag, I purposely set style.display=“none” whenever there is a no-response to the ad request. Theoretically this should eliminate the blank space in the ad slot. However, the blank space still persists. This leads me to believe that the solution to this issue lies in collapsing the ad slot on the publisher app side (rather than the javascript tag side).

There is a method that allows you to hide and effectively collapse the ad slot. For Android, it is .setVisibility(View.GONE). However, it would need some input from DFP/GAM that signals that there is no response from a demand partner. Does DFP/GAM offer this capability in the form of some sort of event listener? Is my line of thinking correct? Or is it actually a Javascript tag issue?

Would greatly appreciate any feedback and suggestions on how to resolve this empty ads issue!

Comment: Thing is the adcall worked as they called and displayed your JS tag, which is empty... You might need to call a passback to give them back the impression you did not use.

Comment: we have a passback implemented and have verified that it works properly. However, even in passback scenarios, there are a lot of cases where even the passback doesn't have a response to the request.

Comment: Also, just fyi. I reached out to my Google POC and he mentioned that DFP/GAM has no way of determining whether JS response is empty or not. Thus, it will always create an Android view to house the ad. This ultimately results in empty/blank ads being shown as there is no ad response but still the container on the publisher's app side is getting generated.

Comment: You might need to program house ads line items targeting your passback inventory to make sure there is always a displayed creative. See [here](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/2811375?hl=en) for details